# Error while requesting to the server from another device in the same network by Axios to express server

Tags: reactjs, axios, connection-refused, nodejs-express-server

while requesting data from server using Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/admin/getdblogo") from another device in same network
, it gives the follwing error:-

****Google chrome** error**

xhr.js:220          POST http://localhost:5000/api/admin/getdblogo net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

****Morzilla firefox** error**

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/api/admin/getdblogo. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

what have been tried out:

in the server this line is added:

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({origin:'http://localhost:3000'}));
```

in the client side the request that is causing the error is :

```
const [Logo,setLogo] = useState(null);
const GetLogo = async() => {

    const response = await Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/admin/getdblogo");

    if (response.data.recordset.length === 0) {

        setLogo(null);

    }
    else if (response.data.recordset.length === 1) {
        console.log(response);
        const imagedata = await btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(response.data.recordset[0].PICTURE.data)));

        setLogo(imagedata);

    }

}
```

Comment: did you test with postman to see if the API works?

Comment: because the code looks fine. If you are using it properly and haven't done any silly syntax error it should work correctly.